# MySQLNonTransientConnectionException, cant connect to database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to create my very first Hibernate app, but I can't get it working.
I've tried to serach everywhere, but I couldn't find a solution that would fix this.
The tutorial I'm following is in Eclipse IDE, but I really like IntelliJ and I have an Ultimate license too, so I would like to work in this.

All help will be greatly appriciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

I'm using a MySQL database, which should be set up properly.
The username and passwords are correct, so is the port.

This is an Intellij project.
I created new project with Hibernate support and added Maven framework.

Below I include the output and my files.

The whole output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=63481:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\target\classes;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Mark\IdeaProjects\Spring\untitled3\lib\hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.6\mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.2.11\jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.3.0.Final\hibernate-core-5.3.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\javax\persistence\javax.persistence-api\2.2\javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.0\byte-buddy-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.1.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.0\classmate-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Mark\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.3.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.3.Final.jar" Main
máj 17, 2018 12:07:38 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
máj 17, 2018 12:07:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false]
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=hbstudent, password=****}
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
máj 17, 2018 12:07:39 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 3 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The Main.java class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import test.Student;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

The Student.java class:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Student() {
    }


    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Edit**

Forgot to mention, that I can query the DB from IntelliJ's Database tool with the given credentials

Comment: Have you looked into this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html?

Comment: I have. That's quiet an old article, and not a proper solution. My versions of SQL don't even have the OLD_PASSWORD function